# Crystal Reports designed with XSD & XML with OPTIONAL elements

Tags: xml, crystal-reports, xsd

I created a report (with Crystal Reports) from a XSD File, and reporting with a valid XML file, but, some of the fields from the XSD are optionals, so they may not exist in the XML file.

How can I have a formula field, to check if it exist or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking a lot on it, i could achieve what i wanted...

The answer was to apply the schema AND load the data.

Here:

```
            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument objReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
            DataSet Dataset = new DataSet("TableName");
            Dataset.ReadXmlSchema("Schema.xsd");
            Dataset.ReadXml("Database.xml");
            objReport.Load(@"Report.rpt");
            objReport.SetDataSource(Dataset);
            objReport.SetParameterValue(0, "Some Parameter");
            CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = (objReport);
```

Then, i only needed to do on formula values:

```
if(isnull({Tableshalala.column}) then dosomething else doother;
```

That's it.

Thank you. :)

Comment: thanks so much for your help ! this issue gave us a big headache !